# How to save value into select pandas rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to save the variable blank_gpa, which is calculated elsewhere into the rows of the df schools where the column 'School' is equal to the variable the_school and the column 'UG GPA' is null. The code below is in a for loop with some other code that works without issue. My only problem is that the values won't save in the schools DF. I check the number of empty values before and after I try to save it and the number is the same.

```
schools[(schools['School'] == the_school) & (schools['UG GPA'].isnull())]['UG GPA'] = blank_gpa
```

How do I save a variable into select rows of a DF based on two conditions? When I run the code above, it doesn't cause any errors but it also doesn't fill the empty 'UG GPA' rows with the variable.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what it is you're trying to accomplish. Can you share a sample of your data and what you'd like the output to look like?

Comment: Randy I edited the description to try to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. np.where() worked

```
schools['UG GPA'] = np.where((schools['School'] == the_school) & (schools['UG GPA'].isnull()),blank_gpa,schools['UG GPA'])
```